# Jenkins upstreamProjects not starting jobs

Tags: jenkins, triggers, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I created a pipelined jobs in jenkins and want to get it triggered as another jobs ends.

I introduced into my pipeline this way:

```
    pipeline {
        agent any
        triggers { upstream(upstreamProjects: "jobname" )}
    ...
   }
```

It does not start when the first job ends. I tryed with the web interface build trigger section and it worked.
I wonder what am I missing to get it work in the pipeline code. 
I also add `"../folder/jobname"` and `"threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS"`.